# Program that verify that some numbers are prime?

Tags: java

Ok so i made this program that verify if a number is prime.I can't figure out how to make a program that can verify that all numbers < n are prime.Can you help me ?

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i;
        int n;
        boolean nPrime=true;
        n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Entrer un numero"));

        for (i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                nPrime = false;


            }
        }
        if (nPrime) {

            System.out.println("Le numero " + n + " est prime");
        } else
            System.out.println("Le numero " + n + " n'est pas prime");


    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to print out all numbers which are prime between 2 and n?

Comment: Just add another if statement to check if it's less then n before setting the boolean value.

Comment: Assuming one and zero are non-prime is there any n for which "all numbers < n are prime"?

Comment: @Andreas yes 3. Then it will be 3 and 2 and they are both prime.

Comment: @rbr94 but 1 is not prime... nor is 0.

Comment: @rbr94 no. Valid for 0 only.

Comment: Yea i want to introduce a number n say equal to 20 and to print all the prime numbers that are smaller than 20.

Comment: oh, you're looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: @BogdanDragan so your question is different.

Comment: @Andreas Yea i think that is.Is it bad i couldn't figure it out myself?...I am trying for 2 hours.I started college 1 month ago and is my first encounter with programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to answer your question by not changing your code very much.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int i; 
        int n; //here is your number (say 20) and you need all primes below 20
        int number; // it will loop through all numbers between 2 to n
        boolean nPrime=true;
        n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Entrer un numero"));

        for ( number = 2 ; number <= n ; ++number ) // for outer
        {
            for (i = 2; i < number; i++) //for inner
            /*from here it is simply your code which checks every number
            for primeness, BTW you need to check for only upto
            square_root(number) so change your code to i*i < number, I
            didn't changed it just to make it as similar to yours as
            possible
            */
            {
                if (number % i == 0) 
                {
                    nPrime = false;
                }
            }//for inner closed

            if (nPrime) 
            {
                System.out.println("Le numero " + number + " est prime");
            } 
            else
                System.out.println("Le numero " + number + " n'est pas prime");
                //if you need only primes then remove this else part
            nPrime=true;
        }//for outer closed
    }// main() closed
}//class closed
```

Answer (score 2):

Well my answer has a `better time-complexity` if you have a lot of `queries`. We can pre-compute all prime numbers less than `1000005` in `O(nlg(n)lg(n))` and then for each query it takes `O(1)` time to check whether number is prime or not. Algorithm used is `Seive Of Eratosthenes`

Here is a link if you want to know more about algorithm:
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sieve-of-eratosthenes/

```
static int MAX = 1000005;
public static void preComputeSeive(){
    Arrays.fill(isPrime, true);

    isPrime[0] = isPrime[1] = false;

    for(int i = 2; i < MAX; i++){
        if(isPrime[i]){
            for(int j = i+i; j < MAX; j+=i){
               isPrime[j] = false; 
            }
        }
    }
}

static boolean isPrime[] = new boolean[MAX];
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
  int n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Entrer un numero"));

  if(n >= MAX){
    System.out.println("Enter a valid number");
    return;
  }      

  preComputeSeive();
    // count primes
  for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
  if (isPrime[i]) {
    System.out.println("Le numero " + i + " est prime");
  } else {
    System.out.println("Le numero " + i + " n'est pas prime");
  }
}

}
```

Comment: You may want to change the [magic number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad) `1000000`; enter 1000002 I get a false positive and if I enter 100005 an exception is thrown.

Comment: @Andreas Exception is thrown at 100005 because i am checking for n strictly less than 1000005

Answer (score 1):

With reduced number of loops

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i;
        int n,m;
        m=(int)Math.sqrt(n);  
        boolean nPrime=true;
        n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Entrer un numero"));

        for (i = 2; i <= m; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                nPrime = false;
                break;

            }
        }
        if (nPrime) {

            System.out.println("Le numero " + n + " est prime");
        } else
            System.out.println("Le numero " + n + " n'est pas prime");


    }
```

Comment: You can limit `m` to `ceil(sqrt(n))`.

Comment: (Not the downvoter) `n/2` is not necessarily wrong, but `sqrt(n) < n/2` for all `n > 4`. At `n=100`, you are looking at a max of `10` iterations vs `50`. At `n=10_000`, it's `100` vs `5000`. If you are trying to limit the number of iterations, you might as well do it as well as you can.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean find all the numbers smaller than n they are primary?

```
ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList();
int i;
int j;
boolean nPrime;

for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    nPrime = true;
    for (j = 2; j <= (int) sqrt(i); j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
            nPrime = false;
            break;
        }
    if (nPrime) primes.add(i);
}

System.out.println("Primes: " + Arrays.toString(primes.toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

stolen from http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/14array/PrimeSieve.java.html

```
import javax.swing.*;


public class PrimeSieve {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Entrer un numero"));

    // initially assume all integers are prime
    boolean[] isPrime = new boolean[n + 1];
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
      isPrime[i] = true;
    }

    // mark non-primes <= n using Sieve of Eratosthenes
    for (int factor = 2; factor * factor <= n; factor++) {

      // if factor is prime, then mark multiples of factor as nonprime
      // suffices to consider mutiples factor, factor+1, ...,  n/factor
      if (isPrime[factor]) {
        for (int j = factor; factor * j <= n; j++) {
          isPrime[factor * j] = false;
        }
      }
    }

    // count primes
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
      if (isPrime[i]) {
        System.out.println("Le numero " + i + " est prime");
      } else {
        System.out.println("Le numero " + i + " n'est pas prime");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Dont know why this is downvoted, seems legit. I am upvoting this

Comment: this is one of the reasons i hate stack, even when you give correct answers people just downvote without even reading

Comment: @NikhilPathania no biggie; happens all the time. Thanks for the upvote.